# .Getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V in my spring hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jersey, tomcat7, gradle

I'm using spring and hibernate in my application. For building REST APIs, Im using jersey and it is a gradle based project. These are dependencies I've specified in build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.4.RELEASE',
       'org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.4.RELEASE',
       'org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.4.RELEASE',
       'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.8',
       'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.8',
       'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.26',
       'c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2',
       'javax.transaction:jta:1.1',
       'org.hibernate:hibernate:3.2.5.GA',
       'org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.3.1.GA',
       'asm:asm:3.1',
       'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2',
       'org.springframework:spring-hibernate3:2.0.8',
       'org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:1.0.2.GA'
```

Even though hibernate version that I've given is 3.2.5, it is downloading 3.2.6 when I build it. When I deploy war to tomcat7, I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V. Here is the complete stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:677)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:435)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:302)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:805)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:745)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
... 52 more
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db"/>
    <property name="user" value="coder"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.myprojects.pojos.AppConfig</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I found in many places that it is caused by asm and they had insisted on using asm-3.1 which I have used but I still get the same error. Unable to narrow down which library is conflicting.

AppConfig class:

```
package com.appdevapi.appconfig.pojos;

import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_config")
public class AppConfig {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;
  @Column(name = "created_time")
  private Date createdTime;
  @Column(name = "updated_time")
  private Date updatedTime;

  public AppConfig(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public AppConfig(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public AppConfig() {
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public Date getCreatedTime() {
    return createdTime;
  }

  public void setCreatedTime(Date createdTime) {
    this.createdTime = createdTime;
  }

  public Date getUpdatedTime() {
    return updatedTime;
  }

  public void setUpdatedTime(Date updatedTime) {
    this.updatedTime = updatedTime;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  @PrePersist
  public void assignCreatedTime() {
    Long curTimestamp = new java.util.Date().getTime();
    this.setCreatedTime(new Date(curTimestamp));
  }

  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  public void assignUpdatedTime() {
    Long curTimestamp = new java.util.Date().getTime();
    this.setUpdatedTime(new Date(curTimestamp));
  }
}
```

Dependencies:

- aopalliance-1.0
- antlr-2.7.6
- asm-3.1
- asm-attrs-1.5.3
- c3p0-0.9.1.2
- cglib-2.1_3
- commons-collection-2.1.1
- commons-logging
- dom4j-1.6.1
- ehcache-1.2.3
- ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA
- hibernate-3.2.6
- hibernate-annotations-3.3.1.GA
- hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0
- jersey-core-1.8
- jerser-server-1.8
- jta-1.1
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.26
- spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: You are mixing spring versions (3.2 and 2.0), never mix versions. Remove `org.springframework:spring-hibernate3:2.0.8` and add `org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.4.RELEASE`

Comment: I tried this but no luck. If I remove AppConfig from annotatedClasses parameter, then it works fine, i.e if I pass empty list to annotatedClasses. So I'm guessing the problem is with the way I have defined this class. I have edited my previous post with the class definition. Let me know if you see issues.

Comment: Remove ASM and cglib as a dependencies and see which one gets pulled in instead. Spring doesn't need those anymore as they are inlined in Spring now (for springs only use).

Comment: Yes I tried this as well. But I still see the same issue.

Comment: post the content of your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: You mean you want both applicationContext.xml and web.xml contents?

Comment: No the content of the WEB-INF/lib directory (which jars are going in there).

Comment: There is no lib directory in WEB-INF. There are just applicationContext.xml and web.xml files and I'm using gradle for build.

Comment: If you generate a war file to deploy on the server there is a WEB-INF/lib directory. Either that or do `gradle dependencies` on the commandline.

Comment: Actually when I deploy war to server, I dont see any lib directory being generated. But from what you are asking, I think you want all the dependencies. Let me add that.

Comment: I have added all dependencies in my original post. Please check

Comment: Ehrm then where are your jar files put if they aren't in WEB-INF/lib of your war file?! Anyway have you removed **cglib** and **asm** from your dependencies (as they should be pulled in by hibernate already). Also why do you include jetty jars whilst you are deploying on tomcat?

Comment: I have removed cglib and asm from my dependencies. Where are jetty jars? I haven't included them. Initially I was deploying to jetty and then moved to tomcat but I have removed jetty jar though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39330/discussion-between-coder-and-m-deinum)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the following version

```
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/hibernate-3.2/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/hibernate-3.2/lib/asm.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/hibernate-3.2/lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar"/>

    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-beans.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-context.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-core.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-mock.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-dao.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-jdbc.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-support.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/lib/aopalliance/aopalliance.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-aop.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring-remoting.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-2.0.2/spring.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${JAVA_LIB}/spring-framework-2.0.6/spring-test.jar" />
```

Comment: I had messed up the versions mainly. Also the listener class I had given was wrong. After correcting these, it started working fine

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with hibernate asm.jar . remove the current dependency of hibernate and  download hibernate3.jar,asm.jar,Dom4j.jar and add it

Answer (score 0):

after googleing two day i got the solution on it, just Remove the all asm.jar, asm-attr jar and cglib.jar, add only **cglib-node 2.1_3.jar**.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` is thrown mainly because you have incompatible version and version mismatches in dependecies specified in gradle or other dependency managent tool's script.

So take your time re-evaluate your dependencies, compatiblities and versions. Im sure this will fix it up.

A more detailed description can be found in here. [Docker Image of Jersey Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283871/docker-image-of-jersey-web-application/47304508#47304508)